# Twitter bootstrap how to hide error message on initialization?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I have simple alert message which should show up only when there is error. However I don't know how to hide message on initialization. If I manually hide the message then error message stays hidden even when there is error.

```
<div class="alert alert-error">
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert" type="button">×</button>
                <?php echo $error?>
            </div>
```

Comment: How should your HTML / CSS know, when an error occured? You also have to manually show / unhide the error message. There's a class called `.hide` which is simply a `display: none; `. Just remove the class on error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php if(isset($error)): ?><div class="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
  <?php echo $error; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

make sure that you include bootstrap.js and jquery.js correctly